# Wrong file owner on webserver but how?

Tags: nginx, centos, php, permissions, php-fpm

**OS**:

- CentOS 7.1

**Applications:**

- NginX: 1.14.0
- PHP-FPM: 7.1.17

I have a webserver that has NginX and PHP-FPM running. Both applications are running by the user `nginx`. However, when my Laravel application start logging in it's own directory the files are created as my own `username:nginx`.

On a sidenote, the log folder has permissions as `drwsrwsrwx 2 nginx nginx` and the files under it are being created as `-rw-r--r-- 1 username nginx`. How and why? I though that the sicky bit will keep the user and the permission to the newly created files as well. Am I forced to use ACLs? I wish I wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the process listing for the Laravel application? What user is it running as?

Your log folder permission has both the SUID and GUID set *but not the sticky bit*. So the files in your log folder automatically gain the group ID set for the log folder - which is what you see.

The sticky bit or SUID/GUID doesn't change the default permissions granted to files. In order to do that, you'll have to change your **umask** value. But do remember this affects all newly created files.

More about their differences here --> [SUID,GUID & Sticky Bit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79395/how-does-the-sticky-bit-work)

Comment: I've checked with `ps aux | grep nginx` just before posting the question and everything was fine. I'll go ahead and read what you've linked about umask and reply back if I've succeeded. Thanks!

Comment: Np :) But from looking at the file owners, you can safely assume that the application creating it is running under whatever username is mentioned alongside it.

Comment: Yee, that is what is impossible. Check the link please: https://pastebin.com/raw/5hb12SGY

Comment: I see what you mean. In that case, can you check your application? It's entirely possible your app is spawning a new process for logging.

Also, can you list the contents of your log directory listing files written by the user "username"?